# Why asp.net control is accessed by '<%=controlid.ClientID%>' format in client side

Tags: asp.net, html, rendering

Why asp.net control is accessed by  '<%=controlid.ClientID%>'  format in client side.

whereas html control is accessed directly by their id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by default, ASP.NET Web Control's `ClientID` is dynamically generated. If you want to access it the same way as HTML controls, you can set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx